# align action button with inputs in shinydashboards

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Hello.

 I am trying to align the materialSwitch checkbox with some pickerInput boxes.

 Here's what it looks like vs what I want it to look like:

[image]

Here is a simplified code of the problem, help please!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

ui <- {dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title=""),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(box(column(materialSwitch("t0"),width=1),
                 column(pickerInput(inputId="t1",label="",choices=c("Yes","No")),
                        pickerInput(inputId="t2",label="",choices=c("Yes","No")),width=3),
                 column(pickerInput(inputId="t3",label="",choices=c("Yes","No")),
                        pickerInput(inputId="t4",label="",choices=c("Yes","No")),width=4),
                 column(pickerInput(inputId="t5",label="",choices=c("Yes","No")),
                        pickerInput(inputId="t6",label="",choices=c("Yes","No")),width=4),
                 actionButton("t7","",width="100%"),width=12))))
}

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

server <- function(input, output) {}

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Also, if there's a way to tighten the space, or reduce the margin between the switch and the input boxes that would swell. My current code also makes one of the pickerInputs at a different width than the others (to include the switch), if there's a way to proportion them so they're all the same width that would be extra swell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply some css to move the `materialSwitch`.

```
div(column(materialSwitch("t0"),width=1), style = 'top: 25px;position:relative;')
```

Complete code -

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

ui <- {dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title=""),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(box(div(column(materialSwitch("t0"),width=1), style = ' top: 25px;position: relative;'),
                 column(pickerInput(inputId="t1",label="",choices=c("Yes","No")),
                        pickerInput(inputId="t2",label="",choices=c("Yes","No")),width=3),
                 column(pickerInput(inputId="t3",label="",choices=c("Yes","No")),
                        pickerInput(inputId="t4",label="",choices=c("Yes","No")),width=4),
                 column(pickerInput(inputId="t5",label="",choices=c("Yes","No")),
                        pickerInput(inputId="t6",label="",choices=c("Yes","No")),width=4),
                 actionButton("t7","",width="100%"),width=12))))
}

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

server <- function(input, output) {}

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]